# Display custom text on WooCommerce Order Received page if specific coupons are used

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, coupon

I'm attempting to display a custom thank you message on the Woocommerce order received page if one of three specific coupon codes are used during checkout.

Our Woocommerce version is 2.6.11.

I've tried a few variations of the below code but cannot get it working, am I doing something incorrectly?

```
//show custom coupon thankyou
function coupon_thankyou($order_id) {
    $coupon_id = '1635';
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    foreach( $order->get_items('coupon') as $coupon_item ){
        if( $coupon_item->get_code() = $coupon_id ){
            echo '<p>This is an custom thank you.</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou','coupon_thankyou');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your IF statement condition where `=` has to be replaced with `==` or `===`. Also with coupons, you need to use the coupon code slug (but not the post ID).

To display a message on Order received page better use `woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text` filter hook, this way ***(for Woocommerce 3+)***:

```
// On "Order received" page (add a message)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'thankyou_applied_coupon_message', 10, 2 );
function thankyou_applied_coupon_message( $text, $order ) {
    $coupon_code = '1635'; // coupon code name

    foreach( $order->get_items('coupon') as $coupon ){
        if( $coupon->get_code() === $coupon_code ){
            $text .= '<p>'.__("This is an custom thank you.").'</p>';
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works now.

---

**Updated**

**For the versions of Woocommerce before 3.0**, you should use use the following instead:

```
// On "Order received" page (add a message)
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_applied_coupon_message', 10, 1 );
function thankyou_applied_coupon_message( $order_id ) {
    $coupon_code = '1635'; // coupon code name

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    foreach( $order->get_items('coupon') as $coupon ){
        if( $coupon['name'] === $coupon_code ){
            echo '<p>'.__("This is an custom thank you.").'</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank so much for you response Loic.   
When you refer to the coupon code 'slug' that needs to be used, do you mean the actual coupon code itself? I've had a look over the coupon code settings and there doesn't appear to be any slug associated with coupon codes.  

I've tested the 2.6 version of your supplied code and can't get it working using either the coupon code ID of the code itself for the `$coupon_code` variable.

Comment: @Connor The coupon code is the coupon name (or slug too).
The first code works as I have tested it… Now I don't remember for WC 2.6 how this can be done… I will try to catch a test server under WC 2.5 or 2.6, to see what is required.

Comment: Thank for the clarification Loic.